# Why is declaration of a string variable in Java capitalized?

Tags: java, string, variables, types, declaration

In Java, when one declares a string variable the word "String" is capitalized, yet it isn't in any of the other types I've run across (e.g. "int" or "double"). Why is this? Was it just some weird arbitrary decision by the designers?

Comment: Can you list all the types you've run across? Your statement would only be true if you'd *only* ever used the primitive types (and unconventionally named types outside the JRE).

Comment: I really only have used primitives. Although I didn't know that `double` is a primitive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Why does is declaration of a string variable in Java capitalized?**

The `String` type is capitalized because it is a **class**, like `Object`, not a primitive type like `boolean` or `int` (the other types you probably ran across).

As a class, the `String` follows the [Naming Convention for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) proposed by Sun. In short, that coding style dictates that **UpperCamelCase** be used for classes (*"Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized"*) and **lowerCamelCase** be used for instances and methods.

**What's the basic difference between `String` and the primitive types?**

As an object, a `String` has some advantages, like properties and methods that can be called directly to them (like the famous `length()`, `replace()` and `split()`). None of the primitive types have that.

**What about wrapper classes?**

The other primitive types have equivalent ***wrapper*** classes, like `Integer` for `int` and `Boolean` for `boolean`. They will allow you additional functions.

Since Java 1.5, the conversion from an `int` to an `Integer` is made *almost* seamlessly. This is called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: What about the static methods in the wrapper classes?

Comment: @gparyani I added a comment about them. If not enough, I could elaborate.

Comment: I'm talking about the *static* methods in the wrapper classes, like `Integer.toString(int)` and `Character.isLetter(char)`.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are objects, similar to any that you can create, yet the reside in the top of the classes in Java. Really a string is just an array of characters, and this is commonly how they are used in lower level programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Because `String` is the class `java.lang.String`, while `int`, `double`, `boolean`, etc. are primitives. The first letter in the name of a class should be capitalized by convention.

Comment: I assume you meant `int`, not `integer`.