# Why is declaration of a String in Dart capitalized?

Tags: string, flutter, dart

In Dart int, double and bool is declared with a low case letter, why are strings declared String?

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702781/why-is-declaration-of-a-string-variable-in-java-capitalized?

Comment: Not exactly, in Java it makes sense because String is not a primitive type like int, String inherit from Object. But in Dart why is String not declared "string" like int, when both inherit from Object class?

Comment: Dart was pretty new and they wanted to keep the same syntax like big languages, Java, so that new developers trying Dart won't face much issues when switching.  That's why they have most of the things similar to it, like `int`, `bool` and `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Not exactly, in Java it makes sense because String is not a primitive
>   type like int, String inherit from Object. But in Dart why is String
>   not declared "string" like int, when both inherit from Object class?

It would probably make more sense to capitalize every type in Dart, *including* Int, Double, and Bool, since all are descendants of Object and all other types are capitalized. So the question isn't why is String capitalized, but why are int, double, and bool *not* capitalized. I assume they just chose a naming scheme that would make Dart feel familiar to Java programmers, but I don't really know.